# Replace text at end of file using a .bat file

Tags: replace, batch-processing

I have a file with one header always starting with H;and ending with ;4

Then there will be one or more Lines starting with L; and ending with ;1

It could look like this:

```
H;;69622;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;4
L;;0092820046;;2,000;;;;;;;;;;;20131216;;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;1
L;;0092825046;;5,000;;;;;;;;;;;20131216;;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;1
```

I need to make a batch-job that does two things:

1) add ;;; before the ending 4 on lines starting with H; 
2) add ;;;;;; before then ending 1 on lines starting with L;

Anyone that could assist?

best regards Tore

**Edit: Added code-tag**

---

Edit: OP's final code version

```
 @ECHO OFF 
 setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
 IF NOT EXIST c:\tmp\barex\barex\ordchgr.edi GOTO :EOF
 move c:\tmp\barex\barex\ordchgr.edi c:\tmp\barex\contents.txt 
 set SAVESTAMP=%DATE:/=%%TIME::=% 
 set SAVESTAMP=%SAVESTAMP: =% 
 SET "add2H=;;;" 
 SET "add2L=;;;;;;" 
 ( 
  FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (c:\tmp\barex\contents.txt) DO ( 
   SET line=%%a 
   CALL :repl 
  ) 
 )>c:\tmp\barex\output.txt 
 move output.txt c:\tmp\barex\edi\ordcgr%SAVESTAMP%.edi 
 move contents.txt c:\tmp\barex\edi\contents%SAVESTAMP%.txt 
 GOTO :EOF 
 :repl 
 IF %line:~0,1%==H ECHO %line:~0,-1%%add2H%%line:~-1% 
 IF %line:~0,1%==L ECHO %line:~0,-1%%add2L%%line:~-1% 
 GOTO :eof
```

Comment: Does it really has to be done in a batch script?
And is PowerShell a possibility?

Comment: @echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (contents.txt) do (
set /a N+=1
set STRINGLINE= %%a
echo !STRINGLINE!>>output.txt
set subLine=!strLine:~0,1!
if /i .!subLine! EQU .H; echo !strLine!;;;4
) I have tried to output this to a file... it seems to be working bfor one line but then what about the type L...

Comment: It should run on a windows server .. could also be a wsf

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "add2H=;;;"
SET "add2L=;;;;;;"
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q20660695.txt) DO (
 SET line=%%a
 CALL :repl
 )
)>newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF
:repl
IF %line:~0,1%==H ECHO %line:~0,-1%%add2H%%line:~-1%
IF %line:~0,1%==L ECHO %line:~0,-1%%add2L%%line:~-1%
GOTO :eof
```

This should do as you ask. I've used `q20660695.txt` as the input filename and `newfile.txt` as the resultant filename.

Comment: Hi.Thanks - it worked perfect. I tried to add a command to move both the q20660695.txt and the newfile.txt in the same process. It said the file is used by another process. Any idea how to do that or should I just make a seperate process?

Comment: You'd need the `MOVE` lines to appear between the `)>newfile.txt` and first `GOTO :EOF`

Comment: This is the job now: @ECHO OFF
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
move c:\tmp\barex\barex\ordchgr.edi c:\tmp\barex\contents.txt
set SAVESTAMP=%DATE:/=%%TIME::=%
set SAVESTAMP=%SAVESTAMP: =%
SET "add2H=;;;"
SET "add2L=;;;;;;"
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (c:\tmp\barex\contents.txt) DO (
 SET line=%%a
 CALL :repl
 )
)>c:\tmp\barex\output.txt
move output.txt c:\tmp\barex\edi\ordcgr%SAVESTAMP%.edi
move contents.txt c:\tmp\barex\edi\contents%SAVESTAMP%.txt
GOTO :EOF
:repl
IF %line:~0,1%==H ECHO %line:~0,-1%%add2H%%line:~-1%
IF %line:~0,1%==L ECHO %line:~0,-1%%add2L%%line:~-1%
GOTO :eof

Comment: and one more question.  I only want the rest of the file to run if I find a file in line number 3 move c:\tmp\barex\barex\ordchgr.edi c:\tmp\barex\contents.txt  So if there is a file then do the job if not abort. I keep getting emty files every time the job runs and there is no file in the folder

Comment: Simple matter to add a check to see whether the file exists - inserted in final version and edited-in to your question

Comment: I guess my previous question was difficult to understand.

Comment: Thanks very much Magoo. You have been most helpful! best regards